# Handling SQL request with parameters and avoiding SQL injection

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

**This question is quite open ended. Maybe it doesn't belong here, so sorry in advance if that's the case.**

I'm using SQL in a real project for the first time, and I'm having some issues. I'm also using php and javascript.
In the web app I'm currently writing, i do a lot of SQL query to my MySQL database. Each one of these query do a different thing, on different tables, etc.

At the moment, I'm doing the following : each time i do a query in the client side code, I'm passing a parameter I defined myself to the server.

On the server, I wrote a switch on this parameter. So it looks like this :

```
if (parameter == 1)
    /*Query 1*/
else if (parameter == 2)
    /*Query 2*/
etc.
```

It's not very convenient. However, if i use a function writing a SQL query by taking parameters from the client, it would be subject to SQL injection.

So to sum it up : how do i create a SQL query in the most "modular" way possible and still avoid SQL injection ?

I already know about prepared statement, but if i get it right, i can't write a full SQL query with only prepared statement.

Comment: _i can't write a full SQL query with only prepared statement._ Why on earth not!!

Comment: From waht i understood (keep in mind i'm a beginner)... In this exemple `SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, City FROM Employees
WHERE City = 'London'`, prepared statement could be useful for writing London since it's interpreted as a string, but not EmployeeID for exemple.

Comment: You are right, you cannot use a parameter to represent the columns in the select list, but there is nothing wrong with building that using text concatenation and parameterisation for the columns in the where clause

Comment: Yes the one in the SELECT part. Why isn't it part of the injection problem ?

Comment: Thats a good question

Comment: So you want to pass column names and tables names as parameters

Comment: I kept the structure of the code I posted in my question. I'm still unsure about weither this is good practice or not.